# Trouble inserting date from select statement Error Code: 1292 MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, mysql-5.6

I'm reconciling two different sources of data.  I am trying to insert from one of them into another based on a bunch of conditions, using a statement like so

```
INSERT INTO `tab`.`listsalesorders`
(`number`,
`name`,
`status`,
`parentProjectID`,
`dateEntered`,
`individualId`,
`taxable`,
....
SELECT 
m.number as `number`, 
m.name as `name`, 
3 as `Status`,
-1 as `individualId`,
m.parentProjectID as `parentProjectID`,
m.dateEntered as `dateEntered`, 
m.taxable as `taxable`, 
...
FROM (SELECT si.number as `number`, 
si.description as `name`, 
si.date as `dateEntered`,
p.idx as `parentProjectID`, 
si.date as `Date`, 
IF(si.salesTaxID='NJ',2,1) as `taxable` FROM listsoli si 
JOIN listprojects p ON LEFT(si.number,LOCATE('-',si.number) - 1)=p.number
GROUP BY si.number) as m;
```

and I am getting `Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '498' for column 'dateEntered' at row 1`.

I looked through my `SELECT` statement data in another tab, adding on a `HAVING dateEntered LIKE '%498%'` as well as `HAVING dateEntered IS NULL` and `HAVING dateEntered = ''` as I've read both of those can cause problems, but not a single row appears.  Just looking at the data and ordering it by `dateEntered`, I see no issues at either tail end.

What is causing this and how can I fix it or work around it?

Comment: Why are you inserting `m.parentProjectID` into `dateEntered`?

Comment: Yea I see the 498 now in the parentID first row of my select query, but I don't see how I am doing it in my insert with `m.parentProjectID as `parentProjectID`,
m.dateEntered as `dateEntered`, ` and `si.date as `dateEntered`,
p.idx as `parentProjectID`,`.  Can you explain where I am going wrong/what needs to change?

Comment: Move `-1 as individualId,` after `m.dateEntered as`dateEntered,`

Comment: Oh I see the order between my INSERT and my SELECT being off caused this?  I thought just by explicitly naming them I'd be ok.

Comment: No, it's the order of the column definitions that decide what values get put in which columns, not the names.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.

Comment: You thought wrong :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) statements the column names (or aliases) don't matter. The order of the columns in INSERT and in SELECT must match. Example:

```
INSERT into test_table (a, b, c)
SELECT
  'c' as c,
  'b' as b,
  'a' as a
```

is the same as

```
INSERT into test_table (a, b, c)
SELECT 'c', 'b', 'a'
```

or

```
INSERT into test_table (a, b, c)
VALUES ('c', 'b', 'a')
```

In the table you will have

```
a   | b   | c
----|-----|----
'c' | 'b' | 'a'
```

In other words: The columns are matched not by their names but by their position.